# How to get a list of objects from Guice by their classes?

Tags: java, guice

I defined some "transformers" (functions) and need a list of them. Each of them gets created by Guice and I'm using this code to get the list:

```
public class CombinedTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {
    @Inject CombinedTransformer(
            FirstTransformer firstTransformer,
            SecondTransformer secondTransformer,
            ThirdTransformer thirdTransformer) {
        transformers = ImmutableList.of(
                firstTransformer,
                secondTransformer,
                thirdTransformer);
```

My list is pretty long, so I wonder if there's a simpler way, something like

```
public class CombinedTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {
    @Inject CombinedTransformer(Injector injector) {
        transformers = injector.getList(
            FirstTransformer.class,
            SecondTransformer.class,
            ThirdTransformer.class);
    }
}
```

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multibindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings) for this:

```
Multibinder<AbstractTransformer> multibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), AbstractTransformer.class);
multibinder.addBinding().to(FirstTransformer.class);
multibinder.addBinding().to(SecondTransformer.class);
multibinder.addBinding().to(ThirdsTransformer.class);
```

Then you can inject `Set<AbstractTransformer>`:

```
@Inject
CombinedTransformer(Set<AbstractTransformer> transformers) {
    // do whatever you want with the set
}
```

But you can't do it without using multibindings directly. If you really need to get a list of objects using statically known list of classes, you can write a wrapper around an injector and use it:

```
public class ListInjectorWrapper {
    private final Injector injector;

    @Inject
    ListInjectorWrapper(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public final <T> List<T> getList(Class<? extends T>... classes) {
        return Arrays.stream(classes).map(clazz -> injector.getInstance(clazz))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Then inject it and use it to get your transformers:

```
@Inject
CombinedTransformer(ListInjectorWrapper injectorWrapper) {
    transformers = injectorWrapper.getList(
        FirstTransformer.class,
        SecondTransformer.class,
        ThirdTransformer.class
    );
}
```

Comment: I really need a `List` as I'm doing a function composition. But I guess, I could simply transform it, as the [javadoc](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html) says "*The set's iteration order is consistent with the binding order*". Anyway, your second solution works for me.